# Finite-dimensional complex representations of nilpotent Lie algebras over a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$

Tags: lie-algebras, nilpotence

From Lie's theorem we know that the complex representations of any solvable Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$ are such that there exists a basis in which the representation matrices are upper triangular. Nilpotent Lie algebras are solvable, so Lie's theorem applies to them as well. Algebras of upper diagonal (finite-dimensional) matrices with zero diagonal entries are nilpotent Lie algebras (with the commutator bracket); moreover, from Engel's theorem, we know that the adjoint representation of a nilpotent Lie algebra admits a basis in which the representation matrices are upper triangular with zero diagonal entries. But is it true that for the representations of any nilpotent Lie algebra over a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$ there exists a basis in which the representation matrices are upper triangular with zero diagonal entries complex representations?

Comment: No. $\mathfrak{g} = \mathbb{R}$ is already a counterexample.

Comment: Right. What about nilpotent (or even solvable) Lie algebras with zero center?

Comment: Nontrivial nilpotent Lie algebras always have nonzero center, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658670/the-center-of-a-nilpotent-lie-algebra-intersects-each-ideal).

Comment: Ok. Then is there any hypothesis (apart from the trivial one: the algebra is an algebra of nilpotent endomorphisms) under which the representations have no diagonal entries)?

Comment: @Giorgio: no Lie algebra has this property. By Ado's theorem it must be nilpotent, so in particular solvable, so has nonzero abelianization. But a nonzero abelian Lie algebra has nontrivial 1-dimensional representations that cannot be strictly upper triangularized.